# how to install flutter path on my windows 7

Tags: android, powershell, android-studio, flutter, dart

i'm trying to install flutter on my windows and when i type flutter doctor on cmd i get error then it exit the cmd with no error message , and i try to write flutter doctor on git batch i get this error message

```
Checking Dart SDK version...
The term 'Unblock-File' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, sc
ript file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path wa
s included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:13
+ Unblock-File <<<<  -Path 'C:\flutter/bin/internal/update_dart_sdk.ps1'; & 'C:
\flutter/bin/internal/update_dart_sdk.ps1'; exit $LASTEXITCODE;
 + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Unblock-File:String) [], Comman
dNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Flutter requires PowerShell 5.0 or newer.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows for more.
Current version is 2.
```

i have made variable name path with this value

```
 C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Git\git- 
 cmd.exe;C:\flutter\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program 
 Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

Comment: It clearly states: ***Flutter requires PowerShell 5.0 or newer.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows for more.
Current version is 2.*** You might want to install [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) and try that.

Comment: Also, the PATH environment variable should contain paths to folders, not full paths and filenames to the executable `git.exe`

Comment: You've also technically broken your `Path` variable because there are default locations which you've removed from it, such as `C:\Windows` and `C:\Windows\System32\Wbem`.

Comment: @iRon you can run 5.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.1) 5.0. I also recommend you to check the [system requirements](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows) page for installing flutter.